# Modelo UML de clases para reservas con fecha

Tags: java, uml

**Hola, qué tal?
En unos días tengo un examen sobre POO y no estoy completamente seguro sobre la estructura de las clases, por ejemplo en mi UML coloqué un ArrayList de "Bloque" en la clase CanchaDeFutbol, pero se me hace un poco surreal y no me termina de convencer el ejercicio, por mas que lo haya terminado y funcione, siento que está mal. Me gustaría solicitar un UML hecho por alguien mas experimentado para compararlo con el mío y entender el porque de mis errores o al menos orientarme un poco.
Dejo el ejercicio a continuación, saludos!**

Un club se dedica al alquiler por hora de canchas de fútbol. Las canchas se pueden
alquilar de a bloques de 1 hora, desde las 9 hasta las 23 de cada día. Cuando se contrata una cancha,
el club se encarga de asignar un árbitro para ese partido. De cada árbitro se sabe nombre, teléfono,
qué días y en qué rango horario puede dirigir, siempre en bloques de una hora. De cada bloque se
sabe si está libre o no.
Además, se lleva un registro de qué días y en qué horarios está reservada cada cancha. De esa
manera se puede saber cuál es la disponibilidad en caso de un nuevo pedido de reserva.
Al realizarse una nueva reserva, lo que se hace es:
I. Se le pregunta al usuario el día y el horario deseado.
II. Se verifica si hay alguna cancha disponible en el día y horario solicitado.
III. Se verifica que haya algún árbitro disponible para asignar.

En caso de que no ser posible hacer la reserva (por falta de cancha y/o árbitro) se le informa al
usuario y termina el proceso, de lo contrario, se continúa:

IV. En caso de que haya disponibilidad de cancha y de árbitro se le pide al usuario a nombre
de quién debe quedar registrada la reserva y cuánto abonará en concepto de seña.
V. Se registra la reserva, asociándola a la cancha correspondiente en el día y horario elegido,
guardando también a nombre de quién está hecha la reserva y cuánto pagó en concepto
de seña.
Por último, se asigna el árbitro elegido, marcando en su agenda que ese horario ya lo tiene
ocupado.

Realizar el método reservarCancha, sin parámetros, que devuelve un valor
booleano true en caso de haber podido realizar la reserva en forma exitosa o false en caso
contrario. Para este punto, desarrollar los métodos privados que hagan falta para cargar la
información necesaria vía teclado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega el UML que tienes hecho. Es importante que junto con la pregunta agregues tus avances.

Comment: Listo! muchas gracias

Comment: Los diagramas UML son muchos, por lo que veo, te refieres a un diagrama de clases, seria bueno que lo especificaras.